# How to Use Custom Subscriber Attributes in a Triggered Email

Tags: email, custom, list

I am using a Microsite to hold a page which allows users to generate a PDF, and then either download it, view it, or email it to someone else.  I have generated the PDF successfully, but  I'm having trouble integrating the data from the user and the person they are emailing into the list I'm using for triggering the email send.

My Microsite landing page looks like this:

```
%%[
if empty(RequestParameter("e_name")) != 'true' and empty(RequestParameter("e_id")) != 'true' and empty(RequestParameter("e_company")) != 'true' and empty(RequestParameter("f_name")) != 'true' and empty(RequestParameter("f_email")) != 'true' then

var @ts_owner, @ts_subscriber, @ts, @ts_definition
var @e_name, @e_id, @e_company, @f_name, @f_email

set @ts_subscriber = CreateObject("Subscriber")
set @ts_definition = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
set @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")

set @e_name = RequestParameter('e_name')
set @e_id = RequestParameter('e_id')
set @e_company = RequestParameter('e_company')
set @f_name = RequestParameter('f_name')
set @f_email = RequestParameter('f_email')

var @ts_e_name, @ts_e_id, @ts_e_company, @ts_f_name

Set @ts_e_name = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_e_name, "Name", "EmployeeName")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_e_name, "Value", @e_name)

Set @ts_e_company = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_e_company, "Name", "Company")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_e_company, "Value", @e_company)

set @ts_f_name = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_f_name, "Name", "FamilyMemberName")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_f_name, "Value", @f_name)

SetObjectProperty(@ts_subscriber, "SubscriberKey", @e_id)
SetObjectProperty(@ts_subscriber, "EmailAddress", @f_email)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_subscriber, "Attributes", @ts_e_name)
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_subscriber, "Attributes", @ts_f_name)
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_subscriber, "Attributes", @ts_e_company)

SetObjectProperty(@ts_definition, "CustomerKey", "495")

SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @ts_definition)
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_subscriber)
Set @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

IF @ts_statusCode != "OK"  THEN
    Set @StatusMessage = Concat("Email Send Failed: Error | ",@errorCode)," | ",@ts_statusMsg)  
ELSE
    Set @StatusMessage = Concat("<strong>Email Sent Successfully</strong><br><li>",RequestParameter("SendEmailID")," was sent successfully to ",v(@f_email),"<br><li>Please note: Triggered sends can take up to 20 minutes to arrive in your inbox")
ENDIF
]%%
<h1>%%=v(@StatusMessage)=%%</h1>
%%[else]%%
<h1>NO DATA</h1>
%%[endif]%%
```

How do I use the custom attributes like FamilyMemberName and Company?

***EDIT:***

I have changed the way that I am approaching this problem, storing the custom attributes in a data extension, but I still need to find a way to pass the value of @e_id to the email somehow so I can look up the rest of the data in the data extension.

The data is stored in the data extension just fine, and if I hard code the lookup to a valid ID then there are no problems, but I don't know how to dynamically pass in the ID when the email is sent.

The relevant portion of my email looks like:
    %%[
    var @f_name, @e_fname, @e_lname, @sub_key

```
set @sub_key = 58817

if @sub_key != "" then
    set @f_name = Lookup('Employee Purchase Plan - EPP', "familyMemberName", "empID", @sub_key)
    set @e_fname = Lookup('Employee Purchase Plan - EPP', "firstName", "empID", @sub_key)
    set @e_lname = Lookup('Employee Purchase Plan - EPP', "lastName", "empID", @sub_key)
else
    set @f_name = "BROKEN"
    set @e_fname = "INVALID"
    set @e_lname = "ID"
endif
]%%
```

I want @sub_key to be the ID of the subscriber that is initiating the request/trigger, rather than hard coding it.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, I believe all you should need to do is change:

```
set @sub_key = 58817
```

To:

```
set @sub_key = _SubscriberKey
```

`_SubscriberKey` is a system variable which is always available in the context of an email.