# is it possible? pdf - exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

Came across this link-[How to Use Custom Subscriber Attributes in a Triggered Email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45676/how-to-use-custom-subscriber-attributes-in-a-triggered-email)

Based on above i wonder is it possible to do ??:

1. Landing page to display list of subscibers in the list.
2. A button on LP to generate a PDF, and option to either download it, view it, or email it to someone else.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to build the PDF document itself (browser pdf viewing plugin will allow download). This is most simply done with a 3rd party library. Since it's on a landing page you will not have access to server-side processing other than SSJS so JS is your best bet.

Try: http://parall.ax/products/jspdf
Check the HTML Renderer functionality -- if the list is styled in any way this should make things easy (will just accept the list's container and parse that)

In terms of emailing it to someone else... This is much trickier. Basically you would need to first save the file to the server and then create a link with a mailto: address as the href which contains an &attachment="\myhost\my_folder\my_file.pdf" at the end. This is probably possible but not at all simple.

Comment: i give a try ...