# Can we generate PDF in ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, pdf, ssjs

I want to generate PDF document on the basis of data available in my customer DataExtension and print it in proper format so that it can be sent to customer by a email. is there any [AmpScript](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_functions/), [SSJS](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/), [API AmpScript](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/)  functions or any other way to generate PDF document in ExactTarget?

If anyone has any ideas or experience with this your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just build a dynamic email?

Comment: Hi Adam, we need to attached the generated PDF in emails and don't want to use dynamic email.

Comment: Obviously, business requirements are, well, requirements.  However, sometimes it's best not to put any cumbersome barriers between the data and your customers.  PDFs are a barrier, especially in when a simple email is such a flexible and accessible medium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be to generate the PDFs outside the platform.

I suppose you could build a [Script Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/server_side_javascript_activity/) that uses some sort of JS library (like referenced in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47651/is-it-possible-pdf-exacttarget)) to generate the PDF from HTML and then [create a Portfolio object](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/creating-a-portfolio-object-via-the-web-service-api.html) for it with the [SSJS](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/)/[AMPscript](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/) API functions. It'd be a good idea to build all of the PDFs for your audience in advance by adding aforementioned Script Activity to an [Automation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/).

Once the PDF has been uploaded to the Portfolio (or simply accessible via public web address), then you can certainly attach it to an email in the platform with the [AttachFile()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/AttachFile.html) AMPScript function.

Comment: Thanks Adam! Maybe its better to generate PDFs outside the platform.