# marketing cloud - can I use a third party javascript library inside email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, libraries

I need to use a third party javascript library inside email that is triggered after clicking on a button inside the email.

I need to convert my email to pdf and allow a user to download the pdf version clicking on it.

I found the library for pdf creation, Is it possible to include inside the email code?

Considering that this is probably not the best practice, what is the best way to do that?

thanks

Comment: No - you will not have much luck with using JS in an email. This is against all recommendations, and will see no to limited support in email clients. Instead of asking how to use JS in emails, please share what you need to achieve, as this seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It got better after your last edit. But we're still not quite there. I see you want to create a PDF file, hence I assume we are speaking of SSJS? What do you want to be included in that PDF file? There is thread on this topic [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124391/can-we-generate-pdf-in-exacttarget), which might answer your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you cannot run Client-Side Javascript inside of an email. This is because pretty much every ISP that sees this email will instantly flag it as a security risk and discard it. Potentially adding you to a blacklist as well.

Now if you are looking at Server-Side Javascript (SFMC version) then unfortunately that client-side JS library is not going to help you. Even if you could get it into the email, I would bet a good majority of the capabilities are not supported in SFMC SSJS. Making it useless.

Your best bet if it absolutely, positively MUST be taken care of in SFMC would be to have a link to a cloud page that passes the VAWP (View As WebPage) link as a parameter to this page. This page would then utilize a GET to that VAWP link to get the corresponding HTML. From there you can then use your JS library (Client-side as it is now a landing page and not an email) to translate the HTML to a PDF.

Keep in mind though that doing this means that every time someone clicks that link, it will cost you a super message (page view = 1 super message) each time it is loaded.

This also creates the possibility that if the VAWP link is broken for some reason, that the PDF produced will not be correct.

Comment: thank u, if instead of using a VAWP, I do use another webpage, I do not consume a super message, right?

Comment: if you host the Javascript page that is going to build the PDF outside of SFMC, then that would remove the extra costs (aka super messages) but you would need to pass the VAWP link in order to gather the HTML from the email.